# Using pseudo-random number engines in deterministic, multi-threaded applications?

Tags: multithreading, random, c++11, stl

I'm trying to use the C++11 random number generators to shuffle decks of cards.  I've discovered (by looking in the implementation) that the random number sequence produced by two engines are the same if the engines are seeded with the same value.

Consider the following code:

```
DECK::DECK()
{
    // Initialize deck to contain the standard 52 cards in an unsorted manner.
}

void DECK::shuffle()
{
    std::default_random_engine e;
    // Use 'e' to shuffle the deck
}

int main(int, char* [])
{
    DECK d1, d2;
    d1.shuffle();
    d2.shuffle(); 

    // 'd1' and 'd2' are identical!
}
```

Here are the specs:

1) Program output is deterministic (i.e. same input produces same output).

2) Multiple threads needs to shuffle DECKs of cards simultaneously.

3) Performance is critical.  I would like to not use locks (unless there is no other option).

Due to spec #1, I cannot seed a std::default_random_engine with the system time.  Due to spec #2 & #3, making the engine a singleton doesn't appear to be an option.  Does anyone have a better way to code this up?

Answer (score 6):

Use *one* RNG to create seeds. Seed that first RNG with the the input number, then take the next two numbers from it to be the seeds for the other two RNGs (one per deck). That way you'll have two independent RNGs, but they'll still be deterministic with respect to the original input.

The fact that the RNGs are being used from multiple threads won't matter, so long as each thread only uses a single RNG. (I'm assuming the threads don't interact with each other in a non-deterministic way.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to use your own random number generator by implementing the very simple [XORshift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift). You can see that there are only 9 lines of code, and everything is taken care for you. And it is definitely very fast.

Basically, each thread will have its own XORshift RNG. You just need to seed it properly (just set x,y,z and w to whatever value you want except (0,0,0,0))

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: Have a seed-maintaining object for each thread (e.g. generate a local variable).

Inside the 'seed-maintining-object' call 'std::rand()' and store it as seed for the next call. This way, each thread receives always the exact same sequence, even if the 'std::rand()' function calls differ due to racing conditions.

```
struct ThreadDeterministicRandomGenerator {
   ThreadDeterministicRandomGenerator(int seed) : my_seed(seed) {}
   int get() { std::srand(my_seed); my_seed = std::rand(); return my_seed; }
private:
   int my_seed = -1;
};
```

Since each thread has its own instance of `ThreadDeterministicRandomGenerator` it produces a deterministic sequence.

You can use this random number generator as a basis for the shuffle algorithm.